Get a file from SharePoint-Online by Azure Enterprise App and Postman
We have created an Azure AD Application Registration with API Permissions Sites.Selected (Type: Application) for Microsoft Graph and SharePoint. We granted permissions for a specific Site by Power-Shell CmdLet Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission.
For a test, we try to get mentioned Site and we are trying to use Postman. First we get the Token by



Key
Value




access_token_url
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/token


client_id
client id of application


client_secret
secret of the application


Token Type
Bearer


Scope
https://graph.microsoft.com/.default


Grant Type
Client Credentials



With that, we get a Token for resource "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" which is the deprecated Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) Graph.
The aud claim "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" indicates that the audience for the access token is the Azure AD Graph API (also known as the legacy Azure AD Graph). This audience is not suitable for accessing Microsoft Graph API resources, including SharePoint.
But we assigned https://graph.microsoft.com/.default as scope and not https://graph.windows.net/.default
With that Token, we than try to get the Site with this request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/abc
which of course does not work.
We get this error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-05-07T15:04:22",
            "request-id": "e65ccd4f-5137-42d2-a205-b1e3425a93f7",
            "client-request-id": "e65ccd4f-5137-42d2-a205-b1e3425a93f7"
        }
    }
}

We can see a successful auth log in related Enterprise Application when getting the Token
What are we doing wrong? And why is the scope pointing to Azure AD Graph and not Microsoft Graph?
Nobody until now?
